# Question Migration, and question ban information requested

Tags: support

"Community" moved my question [ASP.NET Core - Application not connecting to database after publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865161/asp-net-core-application-not-connecting-to-database-after-publishing) to SO from DB. The bases of placing on DB was because it still involved "Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers." plus the fact I am currently on a question ban in SO. Of course that would be helped more if people actually upvoted the question more often when they view a question/answer that helps them.

So the main reason I am writing here is because it really ended up being a database issue/fix. After more research I learned I needed to add BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS to my database security logins. Of course this was after I already placed a bounty on the question. So now I am here with a few questions.

1) So does the bounty revert back to me, having answered my own question?

2) Should this stay in SO or go back to DB?

3) Being in SO, I had to wait 6 months from Nov. 18th to "get the chance to ask a new [question] 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions" Will I be delayed another 6 months from the time of this question if it doesn't get any type of upvotes? Or will I be allow to ask another question from the 6 month period after Nov 18th ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Community" moved my question ASP.NET Core - Application not connecting to database after publishing to SO...

Your question was migrated to Stack Overflow by five community members with the [Cast Close And Reopen Votes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) privilege:

[image]

The question attracted two moderator flags, an initial close vote, and four more as part of the [close vote review process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/close/88505). Four of the five close votes were for migration, so that was the [outcome applied](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/167381/timeline) by Community♦.

> The bases of placing on DB was because it still involved "Advanced Programming in built-in server-side languages including stored-procedures and triggers."

To me, it seems to be about client-side programming, which is [off-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. I see no server-side language (e.g. T-SQL), stored procedures or triggers.

> plus the fact I am currently on a question ban in SO

The migration would have failed if a question ban had been in force on Stack Overflow at the time the fifth close vote was cast. I have confirmed that you are not *currently* question banned on SO with one of their moderators. If you wish to explore that in more detail, ask on their meta site or contact the team directly.

In any case, being unable to ask a question on one SE site is no reason to ask it somewhere else where it is off-topic.

> So does the bounty revert back to me, having answered my own question?

No. See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067) in the Stack Exchange FAQ.

> Should this stay in SO or go back to DB?

It should stay on Stack Overflow because it is on-topic there, and off-topic here.

> Will I be delayed another 6 months from the time of this question if it doesn't get any type of upvotes? Or will I be allow to ask another question from the 6 month period after Nov 18th ?

The exact details of how this works are [intentionally not disclosed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142).

> > Don't worry about the exact details of the algorithm used for blocking - in general, it's fairly conservative as far as who or what gets blocked. On the majority of sites, this will affect few if any users in the near future. Most users will encounter [rolling rate-limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) and [warnings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118) long before they encounter this block.

Again, if you wish to discuss that aspect of your Stack Overflow contributions, you should ask on their meta, or contact the team.

---

Side note: I have also migrated your previous question [Limit c# model class parameter call to MS SQL server for non-existing table field](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/167215) to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I did research [server-side vs client-side languages](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) before placing either of my questions here on DB. I was still in question ban as of the beginning of my question, hence the reason for my question in [SO meta comment to Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325881/3527398). As I see now it shows "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more." warning.

Comment: @Edward FWIW The latest two questions (and the self-answer) seemed good to me and I voted accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your time.